# How to copy or insert multiple range data in InnerText using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send email using VBA through GMAIL by using internet explorer. 
I have data in Range("A1:AL4") and i want to put this data in gmail's compose body. if I try with single range like on A1 my code work but it does not work with multiple cells.

```
'Insert Email content
IE.document.querySelector("div[class*= LW-avf]").innerText = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AL4").Value
```

I want the whole data from A1 to AL4 in the email body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim emailBody As String
emailBody = ""
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
For Each cell In sht.Range("A1:AL4").cells
    emailBody = emailBody & cell.Value
Next cell
```

So basically you concatenate all strings in your range and form a single big string which you can then assign to your email's body.

Of course, if you need spaces or linebreaks between the contents of each cell you can do that:

```
emailBody = emailBody & " " & cell.Value
```

or

```
emailBody = emailBody & vbNewLine & cell.Value
```